# Extending a Select in Ember 1.8

Tags: ember.js

My existing code extends an Ember Select:

```
    App.AreaSelect = Em.Select.extend(Em.TargetActionSupport, {
        (...)       
    });
```

Using it like this in template:

```
{{view App.AreaSelect content=areas value=selectedArea}}
```

Now, [apparently](http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_global-lookup-of-views) this way of doing it has changed in Ember 1.8:

> ["views are more appropriately resolved on the application via strings"](http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_global-lookup-of-views)

(whatever that means..?)

So, trying this in my template:

```
{{view "areaSelect" content=areas value=selectedArea}}
```

I just get the following error message:

> "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: areaSelect must be a subclass of
>   Ember.View, not "

[image]

(the last part is, as you can see, missing)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is actually because it can't find a view named areaSelect.

Your naming convention for your select view is incorrect. It has to end with "View". If you rename it to App.AreaSelectView, it should resolve correctly.

```
App.AreaSelectView = Ember.Select.extend({
        // blah 
    });
```

See [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pijaka/1/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you can't resolve a view on a global context from ember 1.8, you can register your view as a 'helper' and access it in template.

For your case try the following code.

```
...    
Ember.Handlebars.helper('areaSelect', App.AreaSelect);
...
```

and in template code it like:

```
{{areaSelect content=areas value=selectedArea}}
```

I hope this might be helpful for you.